# Some Material-ui icons fail to import

Tags: material-ui

I'm working with Material-ui icons, and some icons fail to import, and give the error:

Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/BarChart'

Material-ui/icons is installed in dependencies, and other icons DO import.

```
import StarBorder from "@material-ui/icons/StarBorder";
import Star from "@material-ui/icons/Star";
import Clear from "@material-ui/icons/Clear";
import Edit from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import BarChart from "@material-ui/icons/BarChart";
import InsertChart from "@material-ui/icons/InsertChart";
```

Everything above imports fine, except for BarChart.  I have the same problem with Notes, InsertChartOutlined, ScatterPlot, and a few others, but it seems random.

Is there something additional I need to install to get all the icons?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with bar chart.  Did you figure out how to import?

Answer (score 1):

You must install `material-ui-icons` as the following:

```sh
$ yarn add material-ui-icons
```

or

```sh
$ npm install --save material-ui-icons
```

[Link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10571)

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
yarn add @material-ui/icons --network-timeout 500000
```

actually material ui icons is 44M so it takes time